# All-in-One SDK does not show UPI as an option

Tags: react-native, paytm

I recently integrated Paytm All-in-One SDK with a react native application as per the [docs](https://business.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/react-native/)

But I do not see UPI option under Other payment options . Consider to refer the screenshot as below

[No UPI option shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/398dp.jpg)

Comment: Contacting paytm support does the job done

Comment: I have same problem can you please tell what is solution for this?